# Null pointer when deploying WAR(s)

Tags: java, deployment, war, tomcat7

I have 3 WAR files in /home/local/deploy/eclipse/webapps. They were generated using Ant build files. Now, I want to deploy them using Tomcat , from the command line. The relevant snippet from my server.xml looks like the following :

```
<Host appBase="/home/local/deploy/eclipse/webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
    <Context docBase="/home/local/deploy/eclipse/webapps/VechileTracking" 
         Path="/V" reloadable="true" 
         source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:VechileTracking"/>
    <Context docBase="/home/local/deploy/eclipse/webapps/RE"  
         Path="/RouteEngine" reloadable="true" 
         source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:RouteEngine"/>
    <Context docBase="/home/local/deploy/eclipse/webapps/Main" 
         Path="/GHyd" reloadable="true" 
         source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Main"/>
</Host>
```

The problem is that  whenever I do "sh startup.sh" , I get  a null pointer exception , like the following :

```
INFO: Deploying web application archive VechileTracking.war
- java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:116)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:306)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:324)
    at com.stw.server.infrastructure.ApplicationContextListener.contextInitialized(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Feb 8, 2012 1:13:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive RE.war
- 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:116)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:306)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:324)
    at com.stw.routeengine.infrastructure.ApplicationContextListener.contextInitialized(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Feb 8, 2012 1:14:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive Main.war
- java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:116)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:306)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:324)
    at com.stw.server.infrastructure.ApplicationContextListener.contextInitialized(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I tried to insert print statements in the method that gives an (Unknown Source), but , its not going in there. What else could be going wrong ?  The WAR files are unpacked and correctly so .

**EDIT:** *Hi , the problem got solved. The issue was that  the context path and the app base and the path given in the main properties file were not exactly same. Due to that, something or the other kept going wrong. Thanks.  About log4j, the properties were defined in the properties file .*

Answer (score 0):

The log4j configuration file can't be found at the specified location.

Have a look at your relevant source code, the url or (relative?) filename can't be resolved.

Hint:

start a remote debugging session (not too difficult with eclipse) and make the debugger stop on NPE exceptions. Then you should be able to read the actual filename and be able to copy/deploy the mising file to the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

The log file/directory specified in log4j properties/xml does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

All excpetions come from `org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator` this means your app is allready loading and have prooably bad/missing config for log4j

See your web.xml for config od listener

```
com.stw.server.infrastructure.ApplicationContextListener
```